# Fit a level set field to CAD data

Tags: python, autocad, euclidean-distance, freecad

I'm looking for software that can fit a signed distance function to a vector image or output from either AutoCAD or FreeCAD.  Preferable CAD data because that output is 3D.  I'm looking at coding something in either C or Python but I thought I'd check to see if there was anything out there because I couldn't find anything using google.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You might look into the DXF file type. (drawing exchange format)
AutoCAD and most freeCAD will read/write DXF files.